# ¿Como sea crea un formulario de angular ya que me sale el error There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm"?

Tags: angular, formularios

Actualmente quiero crear un formulario  de tipo angular pero al momento de ejecutar el sistema me sale el error:

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngForm" ("
```

Codigo de Form:

```
Plantilla en Fichero
<h2>{{nombre_Componente}}</h2>
<p>{{listado_frutas}}</p>


<table #dataTable class="display" style="width:100%">

    </table>

    <form #formAdd="ngForm">
    </form>
```

Importe el modulo de form de dos formas en app.module.ts

Forma 1

```
import { FormControl }   from '@angular/forms';
```

Forma 2

```
import { FormsModule}   from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: ¿El form no tiene inputs?

Answer (score 0):

te faltaria añadirlo a los imports.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
 ReactiveFormsModule, 
FormsModule

],
    declarations: [
  AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [

  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```